# The 'RGB_image' parameter must be a 3-dimensional array where the third dimension is equal to 3?

Tags: r, arrays, image, image-processing, plot

```r
library(abind)
library(OpenImageR)
```

This code load the data

```r
path = list.files("../df",".jpg", full.names = T)
#read the data
imgs=lapply(path, readImage)
```

This binds the data as an array

```r
comb <- do.call(abind,c(imgs,list(along =3)))
```

The output of the above is 480X640X18 for six images.
This code is to convert images to grayscale but it does not work it gives an error

the error:

> The 'RGB_image' parameter must be a 3-dimensional

```r
df<-rgb_2gray(comb)

df<-rgb_2gray(comb)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to describe what you are doing and what you want to achieve? Adding non-reproducible code with no description is not very helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:

The function `rgb_2gray()` accepts a "3-dimensional array where the third dimension is equal to 3" from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenImageR/OpenImageR.pdf). Hence, you need to first convert the images to grayscale (e.g., with `lapply`) before you can use `abind()` to combine them.

Before you use `abind()`, the images must be of same size, to force it you can use  `resizeImage()`.

Finally, you can plot the images to see if you are obtaining the desired result.

```
library(abind)
library(OpenImageR)

# set the proper directory with setwd(), for me the path contained 3 jpg images 
path <- list.files(".",".jpg", full.names = T)
#read the data
imgs <- lapply(path, readImage)

gray_imgs <- lapply(imgs, rgb_2gray)
gray_imgs <- lapply(gray_imgs, function(x) resizeImage(x, 256, 256))
comb <- do.call(abind,c(gray_imgs,list(along =3)))
dim(comb)
# [1] 256 256   3
n <- dim(comb)[3]

# display the images
par(mfrow = c(1, n)) # for me the path contained 3 jpg images, n = 3
for (i in 1:n) {
  image(rotateImage(comb[, , i], 270), col=gray.colors(256))  
}
```

[image]